# how to add a driver to the z rotation local axis of an object?

Tags: drivers

I want to add a driver to the z rotation local axis of an object, how can I do this?

Comment: Sorry about my answer, I did not read "local axis" until after I wrote the answer. If I now understand you, my answer did not answer your question. I will leave it there so someone else my find it useful.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, maybe could remove "using python" and the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest workaround I could find is to use the the Copy rotation Constraint to copy the global rotation from an empty (Which we will add the driver to) to the local rotation of the object.

[image: Workaround]

Comment: Glad to have this workaround. Note that for me, I had to set the space of Target and Owner FIRST before setting the Target object. Otherwise, the order of operations results in off-kilter rotation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select your empty.
2. Open the properties panel in the 3D view <kbd>N</kbd>
3. Hover over the Z axis of the location field, <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> > *Add Single Driver*.
   [image: single driver]
4. Open the *[Graph Editor](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Graph)* and switch it to *Drivers*.
5. Select the driver on the left panel, then press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties and start editing the driver.